# Find the derivative of a triple integral function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The function $f(x)$ is differentiable.

And I need to find the derivative of the triple integral function:  $$F(t)=\iiint_V \ f(\ xyz \ ) \ dxdydz \ ,
\ \ and \ V=\{(x,y,z)|0\leq x\leq t,\ 0\leq y\leq t,\ 0\leq z\leq t,   \ 0\leq t \}$$ 

I try to let $x=ut,\ y=vt,\ z=wt $

Then the function is

$$ F(t)=\iiint_V \ f(\ uvwt^3\ ) \ t^3dudvdw$$
But I don't know how to do it after that.

Comment: What does the $0\le t$ condition mean in the definition of $V$? Is it the case that $F(t)= \int_0^t\int_0^t\int_0^t f(xyz)dxdydz$?

Comment: @AlexanderDunlap That's what I expect, with the $t\geq 0$ condition providing the domain of definition for $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with a similar problem:

$H(t):=\intop_0^t h(x)dx$

Let's try the limit approach, which requires getting $H(t+\Delta)$:

$H(t+\Delta)=\intop_0^{t+\Delta}h(x)dx=\intop_0^t h(x)dx+\intop_t^{t+\Delta}h(x)dx$

Thus when we take the secant ratio, we get:

$\frac{H(t+\Delta)-H(t)}{\Delta}=\frac{\intop_t^{t+\Delta}h(x)dx}{\Delta}$

The key intuition of the FTC is that when we're very close to $t$ (i.e., $\Delta\approx 0$), $h$ is basically linear, so that it can be approximated with better and better accuracy by $h(x)=h(t)$ on $[t,t+\Delta]$, in which case the integral is just the area of a rectangle with base $\Delta$ and height $h(t)$. That is,

$\frac{H(t+\Delta)-H(t)}{\Delta}\approx\frac{\Delta h(t)}{\Delta}=h(t)$.

Now let's move to the 2D version of the problem with:

$G(t):=\intop_0^t\intop_0^t g(xy)dydx$

$G(t+\Delta)=\intop_0^{t+\Delta}\intop_0^{t+\Delta}g(xy)dydx$

Let's break up the region of integration into four pieces: $[0,t]\times[0,t]$, $[t,t+\Delta]\times[0,t]$,$[0,t]\times[t,t+\Delta]$, and $[t+\Delta,t+\Delta]$. Then $G(t+\Delta)$ is:

$G(t)+\intop_0^t\intop_t^{t+\Delta}g(xy)dxdy+\intop_0^t\intop_t^{t+\Delta}g(xy)dydx+\intop_t^{t+\Delta}\intop_t^{t+\Delta}g(xy)dxdy$

We can approximate the inner integral on the first two terms as above; the last integral is approximated by a square prism with height $g(t^2)$ and square base with side $\Delta$:

$G(t+\Delta)\approx G(t)+\intop_0^t\Delta g(ty)dy+\intop_0^t\Delta g(tx)dx+\Delta^2g(t^2)$

And so the derivative is:

$\frac{G(t+\Delta)-G(t)}{\Delta}\approx \intop_0^t g(ty)dy+\intop_0^t g(tx)dx+\Delta g(t^2)$

The last term disappears as $\Delta\rightarrow 0$, so $G'(t)=\intop_0^t g(ty)dy+\intop_0^t g(tx)dx$

I won't go into the detail for $F$, but you can imagine how it will work out: we break the cube into 8 regions: one is simply $[0,t]^3$, 1 is a cube with side $\Delta^3$, 3 are prisms with one square base $\Delta^2$, and 3 have only one $\Delta$; only these last survive, and the derivative is:

$F'(t)=\intop_0^t\intop_0^t f(txy)dxdy+\intop_0^t\intop_0^t f(txz)dxdz+\intop_0^t\intop_0^t f(tyz)dydz$

We can confirm this is sort of working by setting $f(xyz)=1$; then $F(t)=t^3$, so clearly $F'(t)=3t^2$; it should also be clear that the above formula will generate this as well.

This also works for $f(xyz)=xyz$: $F(t)=(\frac{1}{2}t^2)^3=\frac{1}{8}t^6$, so clearly $F'(t)=\frac{3}{4}t^5$, whereas each term in the above formula will be $t(\frac{1}{2}t^2)^2=\frac{1}{4}t^5$; tripling this gives the desired result.

Comment: The examples at the end are all just special cases of the integrand being multiplicative: $f(x y z) = f(x) f(y) f(z)$, incidentally.

Comment: True. And there's a much simpler solution if it's separable like that... can just appeal directly to FTC and chain rule...

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a non-separable version that I can actually integrate...

Comment: That's what I got stuck on before even really trying to do it in general: you get denominator terms that muck everything up.

Comment: Well, we can be cheap and just use $f(v)=1+v$.  That's just a sum of multiplicative functions, so it's not really that much different.  Though I suppose you could try $f(v)=\exp(v)$ via power series, but I don't think you'll recognize the answer as any particular function.

Answer (score 2):

Rescaling the integration variables appropriately, we find:

$$\begin{align}
F{\left(a\right)}
&=\iiint_{V}f{\left(xyz\right)}\,\mathrm{d}V\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}z\,f{\left(xyz\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{axy}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{f{\left(w\right)}}{xy};~~~\small{\left[xyz=w\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{a^2x}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{xv}\int_{0}^{v}\mathrm{d}w\,f{\left(w\right)};~~~\small{\left[axy=v\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}\int_{0}^{u}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{v}\int_{0}^{v}\mathrm{d}w\,f{\left(w\right)};~~~\small{\left[a^2x=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a^3}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{u}\mathrm{d}v\int_{0}^{v}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{f{\left(w\right)}}{uv}.\\
\end{align}$$

Next, changing the order of integration reduces the triple integral to a single integral:

$$\begin{align}
F{\left(a\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{a^3}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{u}\mathrm{d}v\int_{0}^{v}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{f{\left(w\right)}}{uv}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a^3}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{u}\mathrm{d}w\int_{w}^{u}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{f{\left(w\right)}}{uv}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a^3}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{u}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{u}{w}\right)}}{u}\,f{\left(w\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a^3}\mathrm{d}w\int_{w}^{a^3}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{u}{w}\right)}}{u}\,f{\left(w\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a^3}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\ln^2{\left(\frac{w}{a^3}\right)}}{2}\,f{\left(w\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

The derivative of $F{(a)}$ may then be evaluated via the general Leibniz theorem.

Comment: don't we get 0 when we plug in a^3 to the integrand?

Comment: @MichaelChirico yep

Comment: @MichaelChirico Possibly you are confused by misapplying the FTC.  In the FTC, the integrand is not a function of the variable being derivated with respect to.  In this case it is, so we need to do [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdt+%28+%5Cint_0%5E%28u%28t%29%29+f%28t%2Cw%29+dw%29).

Comment: oooh right! saw the 0 and stopped thinking ><